# SQL - sum top 3 values in the row as a total of the row

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to sum the row - but only top 3 values in the row... is that even possible?

```
Name - race1 - race2 - race3 - race4 - race5 - total
A    - NULL  - 10    -   9   -   5   -  4    - 25
B    - 10    - 3     - NULL  -   7   -  3    - 20
C    - 4     - NULL  - NULL  - NULL  -  2    - 6
...
```

is that even possible? I only know how to sum all the values in the row...

```
SELECT Name, 
(COALESCE(race1,0) + COALESCE(race2,0) + COALESCE(race3,0) + COALESCE(race4,0) + COALESCE(race5,0)) AS Total
FROM VIEW_race_results
WHERE 1;
```

Thanks for any hint. Using 10.1.19-MariaDB.
Zdenka

I have original data in the table in columns so I can use it.... but I have problem with parameter... but parameter a.Model in WHERE clause is unknown (I have even tried WHERE EXIST when I was trying to use parameter from main query in the subquery.... and now I am lost... ANY IDEA?

```
    SELECT a.Model, a. Name, a.Surname, a.AgeType, a.License, a.Klub,
(SELECT b.OrigPoints FROM VIEW_MiCR_result_data b WHERE b.Race='race1' AND a.Model=b.Model) AS race1,
(SELECT b.OrigPoints FROM VIEW_MiCR_result_data b WHERE b.Race='race2' AND a.Model=b.Model) AS race2,
(SELECT b.OrigPoints FROM VIEW_MiCR_result_data b WHERE b.Race='race3' AND a.Model=b.Model) AS race3,
(SELECT b.OrigPoints FROM VIEW_MiCR_result_data b WHERE b.Race='race4' AND a.Model=b.Model) AS race4,
(SELECT b.OrigPoints FROM VIEW_MiCR_result_data b WHERE b.Race='race5' AND a.Model=b.Model) AS race5,
(SELECT SUM(x.OrigPoints) FROM (SELECT OrigPoints FROM VIEW_MiCR_result_data WHERE Model=a.Model LIMIT 3) x ) AS Total
FROM VIEW_model a
WHERE 1;
```

Comment: do you have more columns or just the 5 shown for races?

Comment: Your data structure does not seem to be too good, the races should be in records, not in columns.

Comment: Your best option is to *normalize* the table so that each record stores *just one* race value per name.

Comment: Don't splay an array of values across columns.

Comment: I have more columns (racer detail, name, birthday, club,...), only 5 races in serie.

Comment: in original table I have each result in onw row.... in this logic -  name, race, rank, points but I have created this VIEW to show points for every racer from attanded races and I need to sum only 3 results from 5, and than create the total rank from serie

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot and then use variables before aggregating:

```
select name, sum(race)
from (select name, race,
             (@rn := if(@n = name, @rn + 1,
                        if(@n := name, 1, 1)
                        )
             ) as rn
      from ((select name, race1 as race from t) union all
            (select name, race2 as race from t) union all
            (select name, race3 as race from t) union all
            (select name, race4 as race from t) union all
            (select name, race5 as race from t) 
           ) t cross join
           (select @n := '', @rn := 0) params
      where race is not null
      order by name, race desc
     ) nr
where rn <= 3
group by name;
```

Comment: I am afraid this is too complicated for me... I got an error message #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_czech_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: @Zdenka . . . If you have an illegal mix of collations, then the default for your database/server is different from the data stored in fields.  You can use the `COLLATE` keyword to align the collations.